# How to switch over the particular property of the array and get the value using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the below JSON file and length of the array will always remain 0.

Sample.json:

```
[
    {
        "session1":"adfuwkko2938893okksjudisojowkekkw",
        "session2":"asfkdkksi2io20909389eolsl0-2889d8",
        "session3":"jfdskdfsoidfosdfi2334234889299209k",
        "session4":"fdsadfkllkpsdiiwkk2388392902019782",
        "session5":"kfksdfuiwllepspoodsfkkllsldlkkmem,",
        "session6":"kdfksdoillsiioepwppeik993289200222"
    }
]
```

I just want to get the value of the above key which is passed as function argument like below

```
const pathToSessionKey = require('../../Sample.json');

async function getValue(keyIn)   // I need to fetch the argument 'key' value from the above json file
{
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
             for(var key in pathToSessionKey[0])
             {
                 if(key === keyIn)   //Checking if the keyIn argument is exist in the json file
                 {
                     console.log(key);  //Able to print the key but not sure how to get value.
                 }
             }
    });
}
```

**Example:**

Ran the above function like below:

```
getValue("session6").then(ele =>{ console.log(ele)});
```

**Output:**

```
**session6** but expected is "kdfksdoillsiioepwppeik993289200222"
```

Can someone help to me find the value based on the function argument key.

Comment: your `getValue` is async .... for some reason ... and it returns a promise, for some other reason, and the promise remains pending, never resolved or rejected, for yet another reason - and yet somehow, your .then is called - I suspect the code you've posted only slightly resembles the code you have

Comment: what your function seems to be attempting to do is  take a key, `keyIn`, and returns `key` when `key === keyIn` ... which, would be `key` - perhaps you wanted to return `pathToSessionKey[0][keyIn]` instead

Comment: the TL;DR is ... `function getValue(keyIn) { return pathToSessionKey[0][keyIn]; }` - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to improve

1. Return promise
2. You could use Object.entries to get key and value while iterating or other simpler ways.

```
async function getValue(keyIn){
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(pathToSessionKey[0])) {
    if(key === keyIn) {
      console.log(value);
      resolve(value)
    }
  }
  });
}

getValue("session6").then(ele =>{ console.log(ele)}); // kdfksdoillsiioepwppeik993289200222
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Everything in your code is synchronous, what do you need a promise for? Also, you don't need to create a promise using the promise constructor, returning any non-promise value from an async function will implicitly wrap it in a promise.

Comment: Thanks Yousaf.. It's just a sample of code and I'm gonna resolve the promise in the code.

Comment: Even I am expecting the code to resolve actual promise, but this code just points out the issues in code.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan my point is that you probably don't need the promise at all. Accessing a value from an array is synchronous, why do you need a promise here?

Comment: @Yousaf completely agree with you. I am assuming OP is trying to imitate promise by returning one from async function, actual code would be different.